# Prime factorization of n factorial

Tags: factorial, prime-factoring

How to find **prime factorization** of n! when n is a large number(10^8)? 
What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the primes up to $n$, perhaps with the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Then mark the largest primes as having exponent 1, all the way down to (but not including) n/2. Then mark the ones from n/2 to n/3 as having exponent 2, and so forth; continue this until you get to sqrt(n). At that point you might as well compute each exponent separately, with this function (pseudocode):

```
factorial_exponent(n, p):
  n <- floor(n/p)
  let t = n
  while n >= p:
    n <- floor(n/p)
    t <- t + n
  return t
```

You could also use the function on all the primes instead of marking them in ranges as I suggested, though this would take a little bit longer.